# Error: invalid mem access 'inv' When Using bpf_probe_read_*()

Tags: c, linux, bpf, ebpf

Here's the problem:

I'm writing an BPF program probing the `vfs_read()` kernel function using kprobe:

```
ssize_t vfs_read(struct file *file, char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *pos)
```

The relevant information(inside `*file`) is collected using a map of type `BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH`. The code of BPF program(`kern.c`) is as follows:

```
#define __KERNEL__
#define __TARGET_ARCH_x86 

#include "vmlinux.h"
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_tracing.h>

struct data {
    char filename[16];
    u32 pid;
    char comm[16];
};

struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") my_map = {
    .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH,
    .key_size = sizeof(u64),
    .value_size = sizeof(struct data),
    .max_entries = 120
};

SEC("kprobe/vfs_read")
int vfs_read_probe(struct pt_regs *ctx)
{
    struct data value = {};

    struct file *f = (struct file *)PT_REGS_PARM1(ctx);
    struct dentry *de = f->f_path.dentry;
    struct qstr d_name = de->d_name;
    bpf_probe_read_kernel_str(&value.filename, sizeof(value.filename), d_name.name);

    u64 key = bpf_ktime_get_coarse_ns();
    value.pid = (u32)bpf_get_current_pid_tgid();
    bpf_get_current_comm(&value.comm, sizeof(value.comm));
    bpf_map_update_elem(&my_map, &key, &value, BPF_ANY);

    return 0;
}

char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
```

`vmlinux.h` is generated using:

```
bpftool btf dump file /sys/kernel/btf/vmlinux format c > vmlinux.h
```

The code is compiled using:

```
clang -O2 -target bpf -c kern.c -o kern.o
```

Below is the userspace program(`user.c`) for loading `kern.o`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <bpf/libbpf.h>
#include <bpf/bpf.h>

struct data {
    char filename[16];
    unsigned int pid;
    char comm[16];
};

static int fd;

static void handler(int sig)
{
    unsigned long long key = 0, next_key;
    struct data value;
    while (bpf_map_get_next_key(fd, &key, &next_key) == 0) {
        bpf_map_lookup_elem(fd, &next_key, &value);
        printf("Key: %llx, Next Key: %llx, PID: %d, COMM: %s, file: %s\n", key, next_key, value.pid, value.comm, value.filename);
        key = next_key;
    }
    exit(0);
}

int main()
{
    struct bpf_object *obj;
    struct bpf_program *prog;
    struct bpf_link *link;
    
    struct rlimit rlim = {
        .rlim_cur = RLIM_INFINITY,
        .rlim_max = RLIM_INFINITY
    };
    if(setrlimit(RLIMIT_MEMLOCK, &rlim)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR adjusting memlock limit\n");
        goto cleanup;
    }

    char path[] = "kern.o";
    obj = bpf_object__open(path);
    if (libbpf_get_error(obj)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: opening BPF object file failed\n");
        obj = NULL;
        goto cleanup;
    }
    
    prog = bpf_object__find_program_by_title(obj, "kprobe/vfs_read");
    
    if (bpf_object__load(obj)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: loading BPF object file failed\n");
        goto cleanup;
    }
    
    link = bpf_program__attach(prog);
    
    fd = bpf_object__find_map_fd_by_name(obj, "my_map");

    signal(SIGINT, handler);
    printf("Press ^C to stop\n");

    sleep(99999);
    
    bpf_link__destroy(link);
    bpf_object__close(obj);
    
    return 0;

cleanup:
    bpf_link__destroy(link);
    bpf_object__close(obj);
    return -1;
}
```

`user.c` is compiled as `user.o`.

I want to get the filename from `vfs_read()`'s `*file` argument, so I cast `PT_REGS_PARM1(ctx)` to `struct file *`, etc.

But when loading using `user.o`, error occurs:

```
libbpf: load bpf program failed: Permission denied
libbpf: -- BEGIN DUMP LOG ---
libbpf: 
0: (b7) r2 = 0
1: (63) *(u32 *)(r10 -8) = r2
last_idx 1 first_idx 0
regs=4 stack=0 before 0: (b7) r2 = 0
2: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -16) = r2
3: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -24) = r2
4: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -32) = r2
5: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -40) = r2
6: (79) r1 = *(u64 *)(r1 +112)
7: (79) r1 = *(u64 *)(r1 +24)
R1 invalid mem access 'inv'
processed 8 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 0 peak_states 0 mark_read 0

libbpf: -- END LOG --
libbpf: failed to load program 'vfs_read_probe'
libbpf: failed to load object 'kern.o'
ERROR: loading BPF object file failed
```

After some analysis, I found as long as I don't use `bpf_probe_read_*()` and the friends, and hardcode a value into `data.filename`, everything is fine.

I'm using Archlinux, kernel 5.12.9-zen1-1-zen.

How am I supposed to get the filename correctly? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

**You need to use `bpf_probe_read` to dereference kernel pointers.**

So your code to read `d_name` should look something like that:

```
struct dentry de;
struct qstr d_name;

bpf_probe_read_kernel_str(&de, sizeof(struct dentry), &f->f_path.dentry);
bpf_probe_read_kernel_str(&d_name, sizeof(struct qstr), &de->d_name);
```

---

**Explanations.**

The use of the `bpf_probe_read` helpers is required here because the memory address being dereference must be checked at runtime, to avoid a crash due to an invalid memory access.

Alternatively, you could use BPF CO-RE to rely on BTF to perform the checks ahead-of-runtime, using BTF type information. See https://nakryiko.com/posts/bpf-portability-and-co-re/ for more information.

Comment: Thanks!  Another problem of the code is I'm not determining whether vfs_read() really had to do with a regular file...